# CR character in gets() function

Tags: c, string, gets

The user types a string, possibly separated by tabs, spaces and "enters" (CRs).
I need to receive all of it; the problem is that gets() function stops the scan when the user presses the "Enter" key. 
Is there another way to do it? I cannot use any other function except for scanf and gets.

Comment: Curious, why can't you use any other functions?  That seems unnecessarily arbitrary

Comment: Feels like a home-work question? perhaps you should tag it as such. Try to ask your teacher for a hint, I'm guessing he'll push you in the intended learning curve.

Comment: This is similar to the posting here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893636/fscanf-problem-with-reading-in-string

Comment: If you need the carriage returns (newlines), how do you know when the user has stopped typing data and wants the program to get on with life?  Also, as pointed out, you should not use gets() even in toy code - it is a major cause of buffer overflow attacks and you may as well learn not to use it now.  Use fgets() instead; that allows you to say how big the input buffer is.

Comment: Thank you everyone! It is a homework thing, that is also why I can't use fgets() even though me and my proffessor know about the risks. Not to worry guys, it's a simple, small homework assignment that won't hurt anyone :)
The user is inputing the length of the string prior to the string itself, so this is how i know...

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `gets()` is really evil. **DONT EVER USE IT**.

It is not possible to write a correct program using `gets()`.

Consider `read()`, `getchar()`, ...

Comment: Calling things evil is unhelpful.  DONT EVER DO IT.  It would be more helpful if you explained the shortcomings of `gets()` (buffer overflows, stripping of newlines) so that the OP could take knowledge to her superiors to push for an alternative.

Comment: Calling gets() evil is accurate.  The normal recommendation is fgets(), of course.  An explanation of why would improve things, though.

Comment: The infamous Morris worm, exploited the gets function within the unix's finger program and overwrote the stack and that is how it spread like wildfire, the rest they say is history.

Comment: That gets is evil is well known and need not be explain yet again. A quick google search will easily answer this question.

Comment: Also, n1336 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#9899) deprecates `gets`, so it might *finally* be removed from the C standard.  Of course, support for C1X might take 10+ years, so who knows when it will be actually removed from implementations :-),

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop. Keep `getc`ing (putting the results into some large-enough buffer), until you encounter `EOF`.

Comment: Using loops is not allowed also.

Comment: If you *have* to use `gets`, you're going to need to repeatedly call it until you've got all the data. How does your professor expect you to do that without a loop?

Comment: Probably recursion, but I'm trying my hardest to avoid that. If there's no other solution, I guess I'm gonna have to use recursion.

Comment: You could write your iterative version, than convert it to tail-call recursive easily enough. Keeps to the letter of "no loops" while completely violating the spirit of it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the "Enter"?  You know by the fact that gets returned that a carriage return (or end of file) was detected.