# How to find a string inside a text file in C?

Tags: c, string, file, text

I need to read a sequence of strings in a text file and extract information from it. The file contains the names and IDs of characters of a game. I need to take, for each HeroID, its respective hero name("url" tag), and then store it into a linked list, but I'm struggling a lot with C syntax while handling text files. Specifically, I don't know how to search for the HeroIDs, get the respective number and url and store it into the linked list.

Here is the only thing I was able to code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct s_hero{
    char name[30];
    int id;
    char attr[3];
    struct s_hero* next;
} type_hero;

type_hero* initialize(void){
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    type_hero* hero = initialize();
    FILE *fp = fopen("npc_heroes.txt", "rt");

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the text file I have to read: http://notepad.cc/howtofindthestrings

Comment: question already have an answer in stack overflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590114/c-programming-search-file-for-string

Comment: @SujithKarivelil, while the alleged dup does demonstrate how to find a string in a file, the parsing problem proposed by this question might be more complex; and perhaps not fully addressed by the answers given to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590114/c-programming-search-file-for-string.  I don't think that you are correct.

Comment: Can I transform the text file in a single string and then search through it with string functions?"

Comment: @RodrigoRonconiRichter Yep, you can use `fread()` to read the file data into a buffer and then use `strstr()` to locate the first occurence of the string you're looking for. `strstr` function will return a pointer to the beginning of the first occurence of the string.

Comment: The name(`"url"`) of the Techies does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_hero {
    char name[30];
    int id;
    char attr[3];
    struct s_hero* next;
} type_hero;

type_hero* initialize(void){
    return NULL;
}

char *strip_dq(char *str){
    char *from, *to;

    for(from = to = str; *from ; ++from){
        if(*from != '"')
            *to++ = *from;
    }
    *to = '\0';
    return str;
}

type_hero *new_hero(char *name, int id){
    type_hero *hero = calloc(1, sizeof(*hero));
    strcpy(hero->name, name);
    hero->id = id;
    return hero;
}

void print_list(type_hero *top){
    while(top){
        printf("%d:%s\n", top->id, top->name);
        top = top->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void drop_list(type_hero *top){
    if(top){
        drop_list(top->next);
        free(top);
    }
}

int main(){
    type_hero *hero = new_hero("", 0);//dummy
    type_hero *curr = hero;
    FILE *fp = fopen("npc_heroes.txt", "rt");
    char buff[128];
    while(1==fscanf(fp, "%127s", buff)){
        if(strcmp(buff, "\"HeroID\"")==0){//label
            fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);//data
            int id = atoi(strip_dq(buff));
            while(1==fscanf(fp, "%127s", buff) && strcmp(buff, "\"url\"")!=0)
                ;//skip
            fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);//data
            //char name[30];
            //strcpy(name, strip_dq(buff));
            curr = curr->next = new_hero(strip_dq(buff), id);
        }
    }
    curr = hero;
    hero = curr->next;
    free(curr);//drop dummy

    print_list(hero);
    drop_list(hero);
    return 0;
}
```