# how do I get a STRING out of a file with fscanf_s?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

Im trying to read an URL from a file like this

```
ID 0
FILE ".\\Models\\Woman2.nfg"
```

And save it into a `char tempURL[80]` the line im having trouble with is the second one.

```
fscanf_s(mFile, "ID %d", &TempId);
fscanf_s(mFile, "%*s %s", tempURL);
```

the first line works fine, but the second one crashes the program
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The line  that says "FILE ".\\Models\\Woman2.nfg" " is a line inside the file I'm reading

Comment: Use `std::iostream` instead of fscanf. Use std::string instead of char[].

Comment: Im in a situation in which im not alowed to use standard libraries

Comment: What are you expecting to get into `TempId`? Your data file doesn't seem to have any digits in it, yet your `fscanf_s` has a `%d` specifier.

Comment: Nice that they are making you hand-code `fscanf`, makes it too easy if you use anything standard built by anyone else.

Comment: No, the line im showing is the line in the file I'm trying to read, TempId is fine

Comment: You have two lines reading data, but one line shown in the file. In other words, you show too much code or too little file.

Comment: Im aware of that, I just edited the question, thanks

Comment: `Im in a situation in which im not alowed to use standard libraries` Then is `fscanf_s()` a custom function as it is part of the standard?

Comment: I just need to know how to do it with fscanf_s please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893636/fscanf-problem-with-reading-in-string <-- Check this thread out.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108334/traverse-file-line-by-line-using-fscanf) is going to solve the issue.  fscanf never reads the end of line character.  This question is more or less a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf_s` is MS's "safe" `fscanf`. It requires you to pass the size of the data:

```
fscanf_s(mFile, "%*s %s", tempURL, 80);
```

The reason yours compiles without a warning about missing arguments is that `fscanf_s` accepts a variable number of arguments and the compiler cannot tell if you've passed enough.

Comment: Thank you very much!  :D